# Where does google.oauth2 come from?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

**Summary**: I want to use a service account to access Google Calendar API with the new `google-auth` library but `google.oauth2` is erratic.

`oauth2client` [has been deprecated](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html) in favour of `google-auth`. Based on the [documentation for google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account), I tried to use a service account (`XXX` is redacted information):

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "XXX",
        "private_key_id": "XXX",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----XXX-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "XXX",
        "client_id": "XXX",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/XXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
    subject='XXX'
)
```

On my server it works fine.

In the Home Assistant docker container, I get the following error:

```
2020-12-06 17:40:21 ERROR (MainThread) [custom_components.pyscript.file.dash__googlecalendar] Exception in </config/pyscript/dash__googlecalendar.py> line 6:
    from google.oauth2 import service_account
    ^
AttributeError: module 'google.oauth2' has no attribute 'service_account'
```

It means that the container does have something installed that provides `google.oauth2`, but apparently the wrong one.

**My questions:**

- where does `google.oauth2` is expected to come from? (from which pip-installed package)
- which legacy package could it come from as well so that I get rid of it? (maybe there are impacting each other).

The following debug messages show the versions of the packages already installed:

```
Skipping unpinned version of package 'google-api-python-client' because version '1.6.4' is already installed
Skipping unpinned version of package 'google-auth' because version '1.23.0' is already installed
Skipping unpinned version of package 'google-auth-oauthlib' because version '0.4.2' is already installed
```

There may be more (thus my second question) - these are the ones I force the installation of via `requirements.txt`

Comment: You might want to try grabing the auth section from this example.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py Google Oauth2 is not service account

Comment: @DaImTo: I am not sure I understand. google-auth was created to replace oauth2client, specifically for service accounts. It gives examples but uses google?oauth2 to import the service_account method